# how to sort images in grid view

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i am doing is displaying 20 images as grid and display selected image in image view .here i consider each image as button. now what i need is after 4 button taps image are sorted in grid view how can i done this pls help me i am very lucky if u post some code thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by 'sorted'.  Are they randomly shuffled or are they sorted in some sort of order?

Basically you can:
  * Create a grid if UIImageView objects (Put references to them in an array)
  * Create an array of image names or UIImage objects.
  * Sort the array however you want.
  * Iterate through the array and replace the image in each UIImageView with the UIImage from the array.

I can't really give you code without knowing more about how you want to sort them.

Comment: how to put references to UIImageVIew objects

Comment: Are you creating the images in Interface Builder or programmatically?

If you are creating them in the program, you could so something like:


 NSMutableArray *imageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];
 
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
  [imageArray addObject:newImage];
  [newImage release];
 }

If you are creating them in IB, just:
NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: image1, image2, nil];  // etc